# ARC IOS5 and IOS6

Tags: ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

here is my question 
should I manually set my strong property to nil to release it?

in mytest.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
@property(nonatomic,weak)   IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property(nonatomic,strong) MyObject *myObject;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray  *theArray;
```

1)In iOS5, which one is correct? function A? or function B? or function C?

```
//function A
-(void)viewDidUnLoad{
 [super viewDidUnLoad];
 self.myView=nil; //strong property
 //I do not need to  self.myLabel=nil, because it is weak property
 self.myObject=nil;//strong property
 self.theArray=nil;//strong property
}

//function B
-(void)viewDidUnLoad{
 [super viewDidUnLoad];
 self.myView=nil; //strong property
 //I do not need to  self.myLabel=nil, because it is weak property
 //self.myObject=nil;//strong property ,but ARC will release it in dealloc
 //self.theArray=nil;//strong property ,but ARC will release it in dealloc
}

//function C
-(void)viewDidUnLoad{
[super viewDidUnLoad];
//do nothing here
//ARC will release it in dealloc
}
```

2)in iOS6 viewDidUnLoad is deprecated, and the document tells me not to care about the IBOulet property.So which one is correct below in ios6.

```
//function A
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 //self.myView=nil;  //strong property ,but ios6 document tells me not to care IBOutlet
 //self.myObject=nil;//strong property ,but ARC will release it in dealloc
 //self.theArray=nil;//strong property ,but ARC will release it in dealloc
}

//function B
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 //self.myView=nil;  //strong property ,but ios6 document tells me not to care IBOutlet
 self.myObject=nil;//strong property 
 self.theArray=nil;//strong property 
}
```

anyone know about the details, wish your answer

By the way, do u think ARC will scan my files,and automatically add "release" for me
below after the compiler  add release(we can not see any release in ARC in fact)

```
-(void)dealloc{
  [self.myView release];
  [self.myObject release];
  [self.theArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: 1: I believe you should set properties to `nil`. 2: neither one, move the code to `- dealloc`.

Comment: in iOS6, u mean I should do it like this:
    -(void)dealloc{
     self.myObject=nil;
     self.theArray=nil;
     //[super dealloc]; can not use [super dealloc] in ARC
    }

Comment: @userXXX `[super dealloc]` is not permitted under ARC, the rest is necessary, yes.

Comment: if in ios6, I don't set my strong property to nil somewhere, there will be a memory leak?
I thought the strong property in a viewcontroller class  would need to set nil. after a object created from the viewcontroller class ,and when the object is set to nil ,all of its properties are nil,and ARC will release them all

Comment: so in ios6, I need do nothing to release  strong property? no need to change 
    didReceiveMemoryWarning
and just set my strong property to nil in 
    dealloc

Comment: @H2CO3
so in ios6, I need do nothing to release strong property? no need to change didReceiveMemoryWarning and just set my strong property to nil in dealloc

Comment: I think yes, you should set them to nil. My 'no' was pointed towards the last part of your sentence, asking whether ARC will automarically release them.

Answer (score 0):

apple_eater,

Under ARC on iOS v5 & v6, because the main view retains subviews, you should make your IBOutlets `weak`. Unless you need to release other resources, you can safely ignore `-dealloc` under ARC. Don't implement it.

Question 1: In iOS 5 with weak IBOutlets, use function C.
Question 2: In iOS 6 with weak IBOutlets, use function A.

Last question: Your `-dealloc` method will be rejected by the compiler. Just delete it.

Andrew

Comment: "Last question: Your -dealloc method will be rejected by the compiler. Just delete it." That's not true. It will be still called. It won't be removed. Just try it under IOS 6.
I use it to nil out iVars I don't need.

Comment: @steve1ae - I think he was trying to indicate that the `-release` and `[super dealloc]` there were unnecessary and will throw errors under ARC, so they might as well remove that method in the example above. You don't need it to nil out instance variables, because the release of those is taken care of for you. You only really need the `-dealloc` if you have some other resources you need to manually free (like malloc'ed memory or Core Foundation objects) or observers to remove.

Answer (score 0):

*“Should I manually set my strong property to nil to release it?”* — In general, **yes.** This is the way, how to release objects under ARC.

*“In iOS 5, which one is correct?”* — In `-viewDidUnLoad` method you should release all objects, that can be re-created in `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad`. That means all views from XIB, all views created manually. If you are creating `myObject` and `theArray` in those methods, then release them too and use **method A**. Otherwise use **method B**.

*“So which one is correct in iOS 6?”* — As you pointed out, views are not unloaded any more, so don't care about `myView`. If `myObject` and `theArray` can be recreated later (e.g. lazy loading), then you may release them (**method B**). Otherwise, just don't care (**method A**).